# Как сгруппировать данные по радиусу геопозиции

Tags: elasticsearch

У меня есть elasticsearch c сотней тысяч точек для показа на карте, я хочу сделать серверную класстаризацию. То есть объединять несколько близлежащих точек в одну. Есть ли у elasticsearch группировка данных как у MySQL? Я познакомился с агрегацией, но она представляет из себя сводную таблицу, а не сгруппированные данные. Подскажите, куда копать?